# How to give a 404 error if there is no page nginx + react.js

Tags: reactjs, http, nginx, http-status-code-404

I use nginx + react.js
Problem with handling 404 error.
This method works `try_files $uri /index.html;`
But if you go to the direct URL or reload the page, the browser will always display a 404 on the existing page

Objective: The site should return a page and a 404 code if the URL does not exist. Is this really possible?

Comment: there should be no space between `$` and `uri` when you put space in between `$` and `uri` it is not treated as variable by nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you are asking how to create a 404 page, not solving 404 code errors on page refreshes.

It depends how you use React and which packages.

If you are using React as Client Side SPA, like commonly with create-react-app, there will be only one input; index.html.

All of your url requests needs to get be redirected to this index file to avoid 404 errors; inside nginx location block with `try_files $uri /index.html` code.

From there on your router takes control and reads URL's; redirects it to your components. So you need to solve this 404 page inside React, not with nginx. (There are ways like manually defining your React routes, but we will go with easier.)

Not sure what router you are using; react-router-dom is commonly used router and i will give my answer for it.

NotFoundPage component:

```
const NotFoundPage = () => (
    <div>
      <h3>
        404 ERROR NOT FOUND
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
```

Home component, or wherever you defined router paths.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/"> <Home /> </Route>
  <Route path="/about"> <About /> </Route>
  <Route path="/posts"> <Posts /> </Route>
  <Route path="*"> <NotFoundPage /> </Route>
</Switch>
```

If you are not using react-router-dom, please edit your question to show which router you are using.

Comment: That's right! We are using SPA and react-router-dom.
It turns out that the 404 page code cannot be passed to the SPA? Our search engines index non-existent parameters in the URL and present them as new pages.

Example:
we now have - site.ru/catalog/item_12345 parameters = 200 code. 
should - site.ru/catalog/item_12345 parameters = 404 code

Comment: You can use packages like https://github.com/daviddt/react-http-status-code or https://github.com/vgno/react-server-status . These 2 looks little bit outdated, but you can search.


On react-router-dom it says adding status={404} to route would work. But not sure about this one. `<Route path="*" status={404}> <NotFoundPage /> </Route>`


Lastly you can use packages like "react-helmet" to create a `prerender-status-code` meta tag.

One of these 3 ways would hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I configured this line of code in nginx to solve the 404 problem after refreshing the page.

Hope this works for your project.

```
server {
  ...
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this method configured, thanks! I need the project to issue 404 code if there is no page. With your method, it does not issue, but simply returns a page with the code 200

Answer (score 0):

You can set meta tag "prerender-status-code" on the html page and Prerender will return a 404 to the crawler:

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="404">
```

You can do it on React:

```
let meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute("name", "prerender-status-code");
meta.setAttribute("content", "404");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(meta);
```